# Why doesn't Azure Table Storage persist the type name when using ResolveName?

Tags: c#, azure, odata, azure-table-storage

Im trying to control serializing of Azure table entities as a follow up on [How do I retrieve multiple types of entities using a single query to Azure Table Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697752/how-do-i-retrieve-multiple-types-of-entities-using-a-single-query-to-azure-table) and have encountered an (to me) unexpected behaviour.

> **When retrieving items the name is always "`<myaccountname>.Pets`" no matter what i set it to when I save the entity. Why isn't the typename preserved?.**

*According to MSDN:*

[DataServiceContext.ResolveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.resolvetype%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets a function that is used to override the default type resolution option that is used by the client library when receiving entities from an Open Data Protocol (OData)service.

[DataServiceContext.ResolveName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.resolvename.aspx)

> Gets or sets a function to override the default type resolution strategy used by the client library when you send entities to a data service.

And [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/12/23/working-with-inheritance-in-ado-net-data-services.aspx) it shouldn't be the case.

**Here is a simple test:**

```
public class Pet : TableServiceEntity { }
    public class Cat : Pet { }
    public class Dog : Pet { }


    public class Test
    { 

        public void RunTest()
        {
            //this.Create();
            this.Read();
        }

        public TableServiceContext GetTableServiceContext()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("StorageConnectionString"));
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            tableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist("Pets");

            TableServiceContext serviceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();

            serviceContext.ResolveName = (entityType) =>
            {
                return entityType.FullName;
            };

            serviceContext.ResolveType = (s) =>
            {
                return Type.GetType(s);
            };

            return serviceContext;
        }

        public void Create()
        {

            var serviceContext = this.GetTableServiceContext();

            // Create entries
            var cat = new Cat() { PartitionKey = "cats", RowKey = "1" };
            serviceContext.AddObject("Pets", cat);

            var dog = new Dog() { PartitionKey = "dogs", RowKey = "1" };
            serviceContext.AddObject("Pets", dog);


            serviceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries();
        }

        public void Read()
        {
            var serviceContext = this.GetTableServiceContext();

            var pets = serviceContext.CreateQuery<Pet>("Pets").AsTableServiceQuery<Pet>().ToArray();

            foreach (var pet in pets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pet.GetType());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am digging into this issue and will add more info as soon as i have some details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and discussion I found that the **typename** is never seen by azure tables (which is schemaless). Instead all the public properties are serialize and simply sent a payload of properties to the service.

If you need to determine the type you would need to store / check a property in the payload. This can be done making use of the reading / writing entity events.

Is your goal to return a heterogeneous collection at once, or limit it down to just one type. If it the latter then it would be good to store the type in the **Primary Key ,Row key** if possible, or in a separate field and query based on that.